# Address Matching

Tags: sql, function, compare

I'm trying to provided results from Old customers based on an address.

To do this i'm looking at the new customers address and then looking at the old customer that was once at the same address.

My issue is that the addresses get put in different some of the time for example.

```
Result 1- 
    address 1 = 37 
    address 2 = Duke Street 
    Address 3 = Chelmsford 
    Address 4 = Essex 
    Address 5 = NULL 
    Post Code = CM1 1HY


Result 2-
    address 1 = 37 Duke Street 
    address 2 = NULL 
    Address 3 =NULL 
    Address 4 = NULL 
    Address 5 = Chelmsford 
    Post Code = CM1 1HY
```

Is there any way that i can bring both of the results back.

I have tried the SOUNDEX function but seems not to work all the time.

Comment: Please add database + version

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: (1) SQL Server is a terrible tool for text manipulations (2) There are companies that this is what they are doing. You are not going to get a simple answer for this one.